# Gatling - how to boost performance

Tags: http, optimization, load-testing, gatling

We are using Gatling with a very simple scenario: reading urls from a CSV file and invoking them.
We get a throughput of ~18K requests/secs .

Are there any ideas of how to push this number up? 
We tried putting the Keep-Alive header in order to refrain from the overhead of open/close of connections, but it doesn't help.
Here's our code:

```
class MySimulation extends Simulation {
  val httpProtocol = http
    .baseURL("http://localhost:9090/")

  val csvFeeder = csv("uniq_urls_500.csv").random

  val scn = scenario("MySimulation")
    .feed(csvFeeder)
    .repeat(10000) {
      exec(http("request_0")
        .get("?loc=${Url}")
        .header("Keep-Alive", "1500000")
      )
    }

  setUp(scn.inject(
    rampUsers(100) over(5 seconds)
  )).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase the number of users for your test scenario from 100 to a higher number to increase load on your server.

Ensure your box from where you running gatling test can handle that much.

If the box is struggling then you can execute gatling from multiple boxes.